# eml file with viewless body

Tags: outlook, eml

I've a big problem because some eml file that are imported in the customer repository (IBM ECM) and retrieve from IBM Content Navigator.
This client demand the opening of this kind of file to the operating system and therefore to MS Outlook.

It occurs only for some of the emails and, by exporting the email and opening it with a test editor, it becomes clear that the problem is due to a series of null characters placed as the last line of the body of the email (I've attached a screenshoot).

Is there a way to allow Outlook to view these emails correctly?

Thinderbird for example also opens these emails without problems but the custome cant use this client, only MS Outlook is permitted.

Thank you in advance

[email body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGw4k.jpg)

Comment: Why not remove those nulls?

Comment: Unfortunately no...
the documents are already on the system and enter by an automatism over which I have no control.

I would need to find a way to allow Outlook to display these emails correctly.

Alternatively I can make an external batch that picks up the emails and transforms them all into msg but this would involve developments that the client does not want to deal with at the moment.

Comment: IMHO it is more reasonable to fix/change something on your end rather than expect Microsoft to "fix" Outlook to handle malformed files.

Comment: Certainly is true, this would be the best chance also if is stange that others program like Thunderbird doesnt have any problems with this file..

At the moment I made a script that "cleans" the eml file like be a text file before being imported. Technically works but it does not seem to me the best solution also because this seems more a problem for some providers and\or like how the extraction tool works.
Unfortunately I have no access to this extraction tool ...

Thanks for your support